# How to Rollback the data by using Java if we Exit the application

Tags: java, mysql, stored-procedures, jdbc, rollback

I am creating a Java Standalone application which has multiple screens.

I am executing many Stored procedures which consists of lots of DML statements.

All are working fine. But the problem is, I should be able to ROLLBACK the data what ever I have modified through all the Stored procedures if the user exits the application in the middle.

Can anyone please help me to rollback the data. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It depends on your design. Are you commiting after every successful transaction?

Answer (score 1):

You have to turn auto-commit off, and do your own commit/rollback:

```
try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url)) {
    conn.setAutoCommit(false);
    try {
        // do work
        conn.commit();
    } finally {
        conn.rollback();
    }
}
```

If the `try` block completes normally, all work is committed. If "do work" throws exception, everything is rolled back.

After the `commit()`, the finally block will still call `rollback()`, but since nothing has happened after the `commit()`, it's a no-op. If you don't like that, you can do this instead:

```
try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url)) {
    conn.setAutoCommit(false);
    boolean commit = false;
    try {
        // do work
        commit = true;
    } finally {
        if (commit)
            conn.commit();
        else
            conn.rollback();
    }
}
```